# Two tables to join but keep index order

Tags: python, join, indexing, merge

I have two tables that have the same column names. I want to merge them but need to keep the order of the index:

```
    df1 
    x       y
0   one     1
1   two     2
2   three   3
3   four    4
4   five    5


    df2 
    x       y
0   six     6
1   seven   7
2   eight   8
3   nine    9
4   ten     10
```

the order of the merge is very important as I need index 0 of df1 to be first and index 0 of df2 to be second and so on.The result I want is the following:

This is to create an excel file to integrate into SAP so the order is very important . Could you help me find the correct merge for this?

````
    df  
    x       y
0   one     1
0   six     6
1   two     2
1   seven   7
2   three   3
2   eight   8
3   four    4
3   nine    9
4   five    5
4   ten    10
```
````

I tried different merges but couldn't find one that respects the order of the index.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please check how to create a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and add your code and sample data as text and not as images. That way we can better help you.

Comment: Thanks for the adcvice! Just edited it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `pd.concat()` the two dataframes and sort the index as next step:

```py
out = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_index(kind="stable")
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
       x   y
0    one   1
0    six   6
1    two   2
1  seven   7
2  three   3
2  eight   8
3   four   4
3   nine   9
4   five   5
4    ten  10
```